# Show that $b \equiv a^k \pmod p$ for some integer $k$ such that $(k, d) = 1$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $p$ be a prime number and let $d \mid (p − 1)$. Let $a$ be an integer such that $p \not\mid a$ and $\text{ord}_p (a) = d$. Show that if $b$ is any integer such that $p \not\mid b$ and $\text{ord}_p(b) = d$, then $b \equiv a^k \pmod p$ for some integer $k$ with $(k, d) = 1$.

I'm not sure how to approach this. I was given a hint to consider $x^d - 1 \equiv 0 \pmod p$ and to use Lagrange's Theorem. Indeed, by Lagrange's Theorem there are at most $d$ incongruent roots to $x^d - 1 \equiv 0 \pmod p$, but how does this help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Using elementary number theory)

Letting $a,b$ be as above:

Suppose $x$ is an element of order $c\mid d$. Then for $k$ with $(c,k)=1$ we have $x^k$ is another solution to $X^d-1\equiv 0 \pmod{p}$ as $(x^k)^{d}-1\equiv (x^d)^k-1\equiv (x^{cm})^k-1 \equiv 0 \pmod{p}$. Also, there are exactly $\phi(c)$ incongruent residues of the form $x^k$.

Now, by a counting argument, we have $\sum_{c\mid d}\phi(c)=d$ which, by Lagrange's theorem, is the maximum number of solutions possible. Since $a,b$ have order $d$ they are among the $\phi(d)$ solutions of the form $a^k$ for $(k,d)=1$.

Comment: I don't quite get the second paragraph, could you please elaborate?

Comment: @MathMajor [Here is a proof of the sum](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Sum_of_Euler_Phi_Function_over_Divisors). Now Lagrange's theorem says there are at most $d$ incongruent solutions to $X^d-1\equiv 0 \pmod{p}$. Since we have exhibited $d$ distinct solutions (of the form $x^k$ for $x$ an element of order $c\mid d$ and $(k,c)=1$), we must have exhibited $a,b$. Since $a,b$ both have order $d$, we can pick one and without any loss of generality we can choose $a$. Then every other solution with order $d$ is of the form $a^k$ by the above so $b$ is as well.

Answer (score 1):

(Using some algebra)

Since $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ is a finite field, it's multiplicative group is cyclic and of order $p-1$. Since $a,b$ both have order $d$ they both generate the unique subgroup of order $d$ in the multiplicative group. Since $a$ generates this subgroup, $a^k=b$ for some $k$. It is necessarily relatively prime to $d$ as $b$ has order $d$.

Comment: Thanks for this solution. Unfortunately I have not taken a first course in abstract algebra yet but I'm sure it will be helpful for others in the future :-).

Comment: @MathMajor Hopefully my other answer is more useful to you. I'm not sure how much it will help but I'll try to clarify if need be!